# Create comma separated query with two tables join

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I have two forms one is for Employee and other one is task assignment.

I am storing data of employees on regular basis like insert it's data firstname, lastname, etc....
But in Task assignment I am selecting multiple employees and store employees details one by one.

Now I want to display task details in grid like

task1  Emp1Name,Emp2Name,Emp3Name...   Edit  Delete

I want to get Employees name all task wise comma separated wise and thier id's as well comma separated.

So please help me how I can join employee table and task assignment table to get 
above type of details in grid per task wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change table and column names if required.

```
SELECT
 T.TasKName,
 TCSV.EmployeeName
FROM Task AS T
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT 
Stuff(
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT N', ' + EmployeeName 
            FROM Employee AS E
            WHERE T.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID 
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        )
    .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N''
    ) AS EmployeeName
) AS TCSV
```

Comment: Great but can you give me suggestion to get this values comma separated please.

Comment: This part will give you comma separated values for employee rows.

Comment: SELECT 
Stuff(
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT N', ' + EmployeeName 
            FROM Employee AS E
            WHERE T.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID 
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        )
    .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N''
    )

Comment: Ohhh amazing I have just update some query as per data I have and got it successfully thank you so much Sandesh you made my day Great :)

Comment: Thanks so much. Glad I could help. :)